# Understanding example of weak convergence does not imply strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

Consider the sequence $\left\{e_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \ell^p(\mathbb{F}), 1 \leq p \leq \infty$, of unit vectors. Then $\left\|e_n\right\|_p=1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\left\{e_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not a Cauchy sequence for any $p$.

For $1<p<\infty$, we can now use the representation $\ell^p(\mathbb{F})^* \cong \ell^q(\mathbb{F})$ : for every $x^* \in$ $\ell^p(\mathbb{F})^*$, there exists a $y \in \ell^q(\mathbb{F})$ such that
$$
\left\langle x^*, e_n\right\rangle_{\ell^p}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} y_k\left(e_n\right)_k=y_n \rightarrow 0,
$$
since $\|y\|_q<\infty$ implies that $\left\{y_k\right\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a null sequence. Hence $e_n \rightharpoonup 0$ in $\ell^p(\mathbb{F})$ for $1<$ $p<\infty$, and therefore also $e_n \rightharpoonup^* 0$ by reflexivity ($X$ is reflexive, then weak convergence in $X$ and weak-* convergence in $X^**$ coincide)

Since $\ell^1(\mathbb{F})$ is not reflexive, we have a choice here: if we consider $e_n \in \ell^1(\mathbb{F})$ via the isomorphism $T:\ell^1(\mathbb{F})\to c_0(\mathbb{F})^*$, we have
$$
\left\langle T e_n, y\right\rangle_{c_0}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(e_n\right)_k y_k=y_n \rightarrow 0 \quad \text { for all } y \in c_0(\mathbb{F})
$$
and hence $e_n \rightharpoonup^* 0$ in $\ell^1(\mathbb{F})$.

On the other hand, we do not have $e_n \rightharpoonup 0$, since the constant sequence $y:=\{1\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{F}) \cong \ell^1(\mathbb{F})^*$ satisfies
$$
\left\langle T y, e_n\right\rangle_{\ell^1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(e_n\right)_k y_k=y_n=1\neq 0 \quad \text { for all } n \in \mathbb{N} .
$$

But $c_0(\mathbb{F}) \subset \ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{F})$, and hence the only candidate for the weak limit is 0. This shows that $\left\{e_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ cannot converge weakly at all.

My questions regarding this example are:

1. Why does $c_0(\mathbb{F}) \subset \ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{F})$ mean that the only candidate for the weak limit is 0? I dont get the relation of what was proven so far with this inclusion.
2. Only the first part of the example (where $1 < p < \infty$) shows that weak convergence does not imply strong convergence, right? What conclusion can I take from the second part where $p=1$?

Comment: When you write $\rightharpoonup$, do you mean weak convergence?

Comment: 1) Because $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$, so to converge weakly, a sequence must converge for functionals induced from $c_0$, and for those it converges to zero, so the limit if exists must be zero.  2) See [Schur's Theorem](https://regularize.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/an-elementry-proof-of-schurs-theorem).

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes, it means weak convergence

Comment: @ChadK 1. What do you mean with functionals induced from $c_0$? Do you mean elements of the dual space $c_0^*$?  But my confusion is that when $p=1$ we are mapping $e_n$ via $T$ to $c_0^*$, while when $p=\infty$ we are mapping $e_n$ to $\mathbb{F}$. So we are kind of comparing weak convergence with weak-* convergence. 
2. Schurs theorem has not been introduced up to this point in this book and I think they are not introducing it in this book... But does it mean that weak convergence is equivalent to strong convergence in $\ell^1(\mathbb{F})$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $e_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $\ell^1$ where $u\in\ell^1$.

Case 1: $u\ne 0$.  Then there exists some $n_0$ such that $u_{n_0}\ne 0$.  Let $F_1$ be the functional on $\ell^1$ given by $F_1(v)=v_{n_0}$.  It is bounded because $|v_{n_0}|\le\|v\|_1$ for all $v\in \ell^1$.  We have $F_1(e_n)=0$ for all $n>n_0$ so $\lim_{n\to+\infty}F_1(e_n)=0$.  On the other hand $F_1(u)=u_{n_0}\ne 0$.  This contradicts $e_n \rightharpoonup u$.

Case 2: $u=0$.  Let $F_2$ be the functional on $\ell^1$ given by $F_2(v)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty v_k$.  This is also bounded because $|\sum_{k=1}^\infty v_k|\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty |v_k|=\|v\|_1$.  We have $F_2(e_n)=1$ for all $n$, but $F_2(u)=F_2(0)=0$, contradicting $e_n \rightharpoonup u$.

In either case there's a contradiction to $e_n \rightharpoonup u$ so the sequence $(e_n)_n$ does not converge in $\ell^1$.

Schur's theorem (from 1921) proves that weak convergence *of a sequence* in $\ell^1$ is equivalent to strong convergence of the same sequence.

This does not imply that the weak topology and strong topology on $\ell^1$ coincide.  A topology is not always characterized by convergence of sequences.  The norm topology on $\ell^1$ is metric, and the topology of a metric space is characterized by sequences.  The weak topology of a Banach space does not have to be metrizable.

The weak topology of $\ell^1$ is not identical to the strong topology, because every basis element defining a weak open neighborhood of zero contains a subspace of $\ell^1$ of finite co-dimension, while $\ell^1$ is infinite-dimensional.  The norm-unit-ball of $\ell^1$ does not contain any non-zero subspace.  As a consequence of Schur's theorem we get that the weak topology of $\ell^1$ is not metrizable.

Comment: So basically the conclusion is that the sequence $e_n$ cannot converge weakly in $\ell^1$ but it converges weak-* to 0 in $\ell^1$?

Comment: @juan19.99:  That's right.  You used terms 'weak convergence' and 'strong convergence' without explaining what you mean exactly.  If you're referring only to *sequences* then in $\ell^1$ there is no point in trying to find an example of a weakly-convergent sequence that doesn't converge strongly like you have for $l^p$ with $p>1$.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot!